aspx page does not work properly on IIS Server
I have a Windows Server 2022 Server with IIS installed. And I check with the method in https://www.transpara.com/knowledge-base/enable-net-framework-iis/ to confirm .net framework is enabled, as below:

However, I create a very simple .aspx file showing in this page: https://www.w3schools.com/asp/webpages_intro.asp
But the result shows the function is not executed at all:

The test page is at https://www.sybase-recovery.com/test.aspx.
What on earth will the reason that cause the problem?
